# Solving ODE which contains two derivatives in 3D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have written an ODE for solving a problem.

$$ \nabla^2 g(\vec{r}) = b  \delta (\vec{r}- \vec{r_0}) + e \nabla \cdot \left(g(\vec{r}) \frac{\vec{r}- \vec{r_0}}{|\vec{r}- \vec{r_0}|^3}\right)$$

$r_0$ is a constant vector.

But I don't know how to solve it. Does anyone knows how to solve it? Any answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a problem that appears tailor-made for the use of Green's Functions. See "Heat Conduction" by Ozisik, Chapter 6 in particular, for the overall approach. Your solution will actually be a bit simpler since you don't have any transients.

Comment: Is the solution complicated? @SharatVChandrasekhar

Comment: They are in 1dD.

Comment: The complexity lies in that fact that you have ${\bf g}(r)$ on RHS, which made me just realise that the Green's Function approach may not be viable. I will post a numerical approach to a solution in a formal  answer at lunch (about 3 hours from now). Meanwhile could you let me know what the boundary conditions are?

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar at the boundary which is a square, normal derivative of g(r) is equal to zero in boundary.

Comment: A square boundary? I thought you said that this is a 1-D problem!

Comment: It is 3D! Or 2D. Not 1D!

Answer (score 1):

Divide your domain into a number of square blocks an assign them indices as shown in the figure below.

[image]

The governing equation can be written as

$$
\nabla\cdot\nabla g = b  \delta (\vec{r}- \vec{r_0}) + e \nabla \cdot \left(g \frac{\vec{r}- \vec{r_0}}{|\vec{r}- \vec{r_0}|^3}\right)
$$

where $g=g(\vec{r})$

Integrating over the shaded block and applying the Gauss Divergence Theorem results in

$$
\int_{S_{i,j}}\nabla g \cdot \vec ndA= b  \int_{V_{i,j}}\delta (\vec{r}- \vec{r_0})dV + e \int_{S_{i,j}}\left(\frac{g} {|\vec{r}- \vec{r_0}|^3}\right)(\vec{r}- \vec{r_0})\cdot \vec ndA
$$

Carrying out the integration over each of the sides of the shaded region, we have

$$
\Big(\bar{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}}\Big|_{i,j} -\bar{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}}\Big|_{i-1,j}\Big)\Delta y_{i,j}
+
\Big(\bar{\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}}\Big|_{i,j} -\bar{\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}}\Big|_{i,j-1}\Big)\Delta x_{i,j}
\\
=
b\Big[\Pi(\bar x_{i-1,j},x_0,\bar x_{i,j})\Pi(\bar y_{i,j-1},y_0,\bar y_{i,j})\Big](\Delta x_{i,j}\Delta y_{i,j})
\\
+e \Big[
f({\bar x_{i,j}},y_{i,j}){\bar g^{x}_{i,j}}\Delta y_{i,j}
+
f({\bar x_{i-1,j}},y_{i,j}){\bar g^{x}_{i-1,j}}\Delta y_{i-1,j}
\Big]
\\
+e \Big[
f(x_{i,j},{\bar y}_{i,j}){\bar g^{y}_{i,j}}\Delta x_{i,j}
+
f(x_{i,j},{\bar y}_{i,j-1}){\bar g^{y}_{i,j-1}}\Delta x_{i,j}
\Big]
$$

where
$$
\bar{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}}\Big|_{i,j}=\frac{g_{i+1,j}-g_{i,j}}{x_{i+1,j}-x_{i,j}}
$$

$$
f(x,y)=\frac{1} {|\vec{r}(x,y)- \vec{r_0}|^3}\
$$

$$
\bar g^{x}_{i,j}=p_{i,j}g_{i+1,j}+(1-p_{i,j})g_{i,j}
$$

$$
p_{i,j}=\frac{\bar x_{i,j}-x_{i,j}}{x_{i+1,j}-x_{i,j}}
$$

$$
\bar g^{y}_{i,j}=q_{i,j}g_{i,j+1}+(1-q_{i,j})g_{i,j}
$$

$$
q_{i,j}=\frac{\bar y_{i,j}-y_{i,j}}{y_{i,j+1}-y_{i,j}}
$$
and $\Pi(a,x,b)$ is the Unit Boxcar function defined as

$$
\Pi(a,x,b)=1,a<x<b
\\
=0, \text{ otherwise}
$$

The idea from this point on is to make all the substitutions into the discretised conservation equation whereupon you get an equation for $g_{i,j}$ in terms of its neighbours. Repeating this for each of the grid cells give you as many equations as there are unknowns and the system of equations can be solved by an Alternating-Direction-Implicit scheme.

You will have to use a non-uniform grid spacing because you want a very fine grid close to the point source without wasteful computations near the boundaries where you have Neumann conditions.

Hope this gets you started!

Comment: This is an excellent answer! I particularly enjoy the image.

Comment: Thanks! I was too lazy to write out the 3-D version :-)